# Async IO Explanation

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await

I was reading the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#example-coroutine-displaying-the-current-date) and found this example:

```
import asyncio
import datetime

async def display_date(loop):
    end_time = loop.time() + 5.0
    while True:
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        if (loop.time() + 1.0) >= end_time:
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# Blocking call which returns when the display_date() coroutine is done
loop.run_until_complete(display_date(loop))
loop.close()
```

**Note:** The comment in the above code states that `loop.run_until_complete(display_date(loop))` is a blocking call.

From [this](https://www.amazon.com/Python-Standard-Library-Example-Developers/product-reviews/0134291050/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_hist_5?ie=UTF8&filterByStar=five_star&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1#reviews-filter-bar) textbook and corresponding [website](https://pymotw.com/3/asyncio/executors.html), I found this example:

```
# asyncio_executor_thread.py

import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import sys
import time


def blocks(n):
    log = logging.getLogger('blocks({})'.format(n))
    log.info('running')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    log.info('done')
    return n ** 2

async def run_blocking_tasks(executor):
    log = logging.getLogger('run_blocking_tasks')
    log.info('starting')

    log.info('creating executor tasks')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    blocking_tasks = [
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocks, i)
        for i in range(6)
    ]
    log.info('waiting for executor tasks')
    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(blocking_tasks)
    results = [t.result() for t in completed]
    log.info('results: {!r}'.format(results))

    log.info('exiting')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Configure logging to show the name of the thread
    # where the log message originates.
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(threadName)10s %(name)18s: %(message)s',
        stream=sys.stderr,
    )

    # Create a limited thread pool.
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(
        max_workers=3,
    )

    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        event_loop.run_until_complete(run_blocking_tasks(executor))
    finally:
        event_loop.close()
```

As stated in the first example from the python docs, `loop.run_until_complete()` blocks, which means any code that comes after it, so if I had a for loop that printed the numbers from 1 to 10, that for loop won't execute until after `loop.run_until_complete(display_date(loop))` finishes.

The second example runs a function inside a `threadpoolexecutor`, and again it uses the blocking call `event_loop.run_until_complete(run_blocking_tasks(executor)`

**Question:**

1. From the second example, suppose if I wanted to calculate `n ** 2` **without** blocking the main thread, I would create a thread, pass the function and arguments and `start()` the thread, while the main thread is doing something else, correct?
2. When using `async` and `loop.run_until_complete()` with a `threadpoolexecutor`, you give it a function and arguments to run, **while** you wait for it to complete, correct? When calling `loop.run_until_complete()` there is an understanding that you are waiting for the loop to finish (hence the function name)? I shouldn't call `loop.run_until_complete()` with the expectation that any code after it will execute **while** that loop is running?

Comment: `run_in_executor` immediately returns a future (which you can await if you want). `run_until_complete` runs a coroutine to completion, it doesn't care about the threads or even other coroutines it spawned.

Comment: @Norrius - but `run_until_complete` blocks until it's completed, correct? Any code after the `run_until_complete` won't run until `run_until_complete` is completed, correct?

Comment: I think that is accurate.